# How to resolve this error with Unity's AsyncGPUReadback?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous

I am trying to read back from the GPU a compute buffer inside of which there is an array of structs that I have defined and previously set.

```
var req = AsyncGPUReadback.Request(myBuffer);
if(req.hasError == false)
{
    var readback = req.GetData<myStruct>();
    print(readback);
}
```

When I put this in the code I get this error: *InvalidOperationException: Cannot access the data as it is not available*. The problem is that the data should be available because when I use the normal GetData method everything works just fine.

```
myBuffer.GetData(data);
```

Does anyone have an idea where I should be looking to get this error solved? Thanks!

------------------------Edit-------------------------------

I found a solution here https://github.com/keijiro/AsyncCaptureTest/blob/master/Assets/AsyncCapture.cs , but It's not very clear to me why it is working now and not before.

```
void Update()
{
   AsyncGPUReadback.Request(myBuffer, OnCompleteReadBack);
}

void OnCompleteReadBack(AsyncGPUReadBackRequest request)
{
    if(request.hasError == false)
    {
       var data = request.GetData<myStruct>();
    }
```

}

Comment: Are you using latest library?  See : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.AsyncGPUReadback.Request.html

Comment: Thanks! Yes I am using the latest library, I just resolved the but it's not super clear to why its working. I'm editing the main question with the solution I found.

Comment: You are not getting all the data in one chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Transferring data from the GPU to the CPU is often slow, and can take several milliseconds depending on the amount of data you're transferring. AsyncGPUReadback is "asynchronous", meaning that the result is available at some point in the future, rather than immediately.

In your example, you check that there was no error reading back the data, but you don't check if the request is complete using `AsyncGPUReadbackRequest.done`. It's likely that the data is still being transferred when you try to retrieve it using `req.GetData<>`. You should instead check `req.done && !req.hasError` periodically (like in a Coroutine, or Update) before reading the data.

`ComputeBuffer.GetData` works here because unlike AsyncGPUReadback, it's a blocking call. Fetching data this way will pause your game until the transfer from GPU to CPU memory is complete. While this is easier to work with, it can lead to significant hitches while data is being transferred, and async read-back should be preferred.